Issue with Brunner-Munzel test - only the rankings matter
When testing between two populations using the nonparametric Brunner-Munzel test, I notice that the test statistic
$BM = \frac{\bar{R}_2-\bar{R}_1}{Ns}$
where $\bar{R}_i$ is the average of the pooled rankings $R_{ij}$, $N$ is the sum of the population sizes $n_1$ and $n_2$, and $s = \sqrt{\frac{s_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{s_2^2}{n_2}}$ where $s_i^2$ is the sample variance of the placements $P_{ij}$ where $P_{ij}=\frac{R_{ij} - R_{ij}^{*}}{N - n_i}$ with $R_{ij}^{*}$ being the within population rank of $x_{ij}$ in $X_i$.  So it seems that if you're comparing $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1 \end{bmatrix}$ against $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\2 \end{bmatrix}$, the resulting test statistic is exactly the same as if you were comparing $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1 \end{bmatrix}$ against $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1000 \end{bmatrix}$.
My questions are:

Is my intuition correct in thinking that the second case should a population "more different" than the first case?
Is there some sort of alternative test, approach or method to correct for this?


The Brunner-Munzel test (BMt) is (quoting from wiki) "a nonparametric test of the null hypothesis that, for randomly selected values X and Y from two populations, the probability of X being greater than Y is equal to the probability of Y being greater than X.". Said differently,
$H0: P(X<Y) = P(Y<X)$ or alternatively $P(X>Y) + 0.5·P(X=Y)=0.5$
If you take your 2 examples, $P(X<Y)$ will be exactly the same in both cases. So your intuition is not correct, as the BMt is not a test of "difference between populations", as you write, but a test of stochastic equality. Your 2 examples have exactly the same amount of "stochastic difference", so will give you exactly the same value of the statistic, and the same p-value.
And because of this, there is nothing to "correct". The BMt works exactly as advertised.
Now, if you wanted to compare distributions, you could use Q-Q plots, or tests such as Kolmogorov-Smirnov. There is even a non-parametric test, derived from the Anderson-Darling measure of agreement, which is supported in R. Under these your 2nd sample may be "more different".

Thank you for the response @jginestet and the suggestion of the k-sample Anderson-Darling test.  This is exactly what I was looking for.
